# Common Language Extension(CLE)

Tags: java, python

I want to use Common Language Extension(CLE) to link Java with Python code to create JDK, however the Numpy couldn't be imported. The error is like this. How can I solve this problem?

[image: run python code]
[image: error code002]
[image: error code003]

Comment: Cool question, please don't add links, rather paste your code/stacktrace

Comment: Welcome to SO! If I were you, I wouldn't post code in images: [why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)